# How mysql handle delete and select query at the same time?

Tags: mysql, select

I have some confusion regarding mysql handler to handle delete and select query at the same time. I need to know if delete query is running on a table and at the same time select is also running for that table and even for the same row.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify whether you are talking about two distinct statements, SELECT and DELETE, running concurrently or about a DELETE statement with a subquery (SELECT).

Comment: Yes I am talking about 2 distinct statements on same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql uses internal locking mechanism for this. Please check the following link also check for locking mechanisms in MySql.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html

Answer (score 0):

if the delete statement wasn't a part of transaction then the engine ,most mysql engines, will lock the related rows until the delete statement executed.

if the delete statement was a part of on going transaction then the ability to access that records are determined with the transaction isolation level.

The transaction isolation level determine whether other sessions can access the data that was affected by the transaction's statement ( in your case delete ) before the transaction is committed 
if the isolation level is read committed and the transaction was not committed yet then any select statement outside the transaction block will retrieve the old data and after the transaction is committed the select will retrieve the new data.

for more details about isolation levels you can check this 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html